# How To Show Form Values On Submission (After Reload)?

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I'm making a web app and currently working on the page where users can enter their account details.

The code currently allows users to enter values for their account info and hut submit. When they hit submit, it reloads the page and saves those values to the database. However, it doesn't show these new values until the page is reloaded again manually after confirming form re submission.

How can I fix it so the info automatically updates?

My form looks like:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="row account-details">
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>First Name</p>
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" style="border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #e9e9e9;" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $user['firstname'];?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Date of birth</p>
                    <input type="date" name="dob" class="form-control" style="border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #e9e9e9;" name="dob" value="<?php echo $user['dob'];?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Skype</p>
                    <input type="text" name="skype" class="form-control" style="border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #e9e9e9;" name="skype" value="<?php echo $user['skype'];?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Channel name</p>
                    <p class="channelname"><?php echo $user['username'];?></p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Last Name</p>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #e9e9e9;" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $user['lastname'];?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Country</p>
                    <select class="form-control" style="border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #e9e9e9;" name="country">
                     <?php foreach($countries as $c) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $c;?>" <?php if($user['country'] === $c) echo 'selected';?>><?php echo $c;?></option>
                        <?php }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Contact email</p>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" style="border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #e9e9e9;" name="email" value="<?php echo $user['email'];?>">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p>Channel niche</p>
                    <select class="form-control" style="border-radius:5px;border:1px solid #e9e9e9;" name="niche">
                        <option>Gaming</option>
                        <option>-</option>
                        <option>-</option>
                    </select></div><input onSubmit="location.href='index.html'" style="border-radius:5px;margin-left:-90px;"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Submit"></form>
```

AND the PHP that controls this form looks like:

```
        <?php if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
foreach($_POST as $k => $p) {
    $_POST[$k] = htmlspecialchars($p);
}

$db->where('id', $user['id']);
if($db->update('users', $_POST)) header("Location: account.php"); 
}
?>
```

Comment: @Darren it refers to the user's name so if posts to the correct account in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your form is either in the file `account.php` or included by it. Since the form POSTs to the same URL, I assume that the PHP you quoted is also in `account.php` or included by it.

If that's the case, you don't need to send a Location header, and just be sure that you query the user information (populating the form's `$user` array) *after* you successfully update the database.

Some clarification as requested:

```
<?php
    // update db from $_POST
    // query db to populate $user array
?>
<form>
    <!-- inputs getting values from $user -->
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got rid of the header, but it is still acting in the same way. "be sure that you query the user information (populating the form's $user array) after you successfully update the database" how can I make sure that I do this? Can you show me an example?

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify a bit. It seems like the essential bits of your code have been left out of the question. Especially where the array `$user` is defined, and where the form is included in relation to your db update.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are getting the form data with something similar to:

```
$user = getUserFromSomewhere($userID);
// $user is now an array with the user's data
//... handle post        
<!-- html comes now -->
```

if you instead did this:

```
//... handle post
$user = getUserFromSomewhere($userID);
// $user is now an array with the user's data
<!-- html comes now -->
```

your request to get the userdata would happen after the changes were written, so they could be displayed correctly.